# SQL Server Max statement returns multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

When querying two tables (t1, t2) and using a MAX statement for a column in t2, SQL returns multiple entries.

This seems to be because I also query other info from t2 which consists of unique entries.

Simplified table example

```
t1.number       t2.number_id       t2.sync_id       t2.text
1               1                  1                'My problem is 
1               1                  2                That
2               2                  3                Multiple entries
2               2                  1                Are
2               2                  2                Returned'
```

When using

```
SELECT t1.number, max(t2.sync_id), convert(varchar(100),t2.text) 
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE t1.number = t2.number_id 
GROUP BY t1.number, convert(varchar(100),t2.text)
```

I get multiple entries instead of just line 2 and 5 from the example table.

Comment: The group by needs to be unique for each t1.number and t2.text - in this example they arent. As each row has different text you will get each row come back. What result are you trying to get ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `convert(varchar(100),t2.text)` from `GROUP BY t1.number, convert(varchar(100),t2.text)`. You are now grouping by two criteria when you just want grouping by `t1.number`.

Also you may be interested on how to get all the text in the `t2.text` column in one single row. If so take a look here: http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-from-a-column-into-a-single-row.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming at least SQL 2005 so you can use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
;with cteMaxSync as (
    select t1.number, max(t2.sync_id) as MaxSyncId
        from t1
            inner join t2
                on t1.number = t2.number_id
        group by t1.number
)
select c.number, c.MaxSyncId, convert(varchar(100),t2.text) 
    from cteMaxSync c
        inner join t2
            on c.number = t2.number_id
                and c.MaxSyncId = t2.sync_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard sql approach

```
SELECT
     t1.number, 
     t2.sync_id, 
     convert(varchar(100),t2.text) 
FROM
    t1 
    INNER JOIN  t2 
    ON t1.number = t2.number_id 
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT Max(t2.synch_id) synch_id, t1.number) 
       FROM   t1 
            INNER JOIN  t2 
            ON t1.number = t2.number_id ) max
    ON t1.number = max.number and 
       t2.synch_id = max.synch_id
```