# How max() function works in SQL-Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find maximum column value, i says:

```
SELECT 
Segment_ID.Segment_ID,
Intensity.Date,
Intensity.NumAll,
Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar,
MAX(Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar) as maxvalue,
Track.the_geom
FROM Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID=Track.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Intensity ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID=Intensity.Segment_ID
where (DATEPART(yy, Intensity.Date) = 2009
AND DATEPART(mm, Intensity.Date) = 08
AND DATEPART(dd, Intensity.Date) = 14)
```

But get error:

```
Column `Segment_ID.Segment_ID` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

So i add `GROUP BY Segment_ID.Segment_ID` but get same error for next column.
How to use max() function correctly?

**UPD**

I think i asking wrong. Bucouse i expect that max() function return me row and set in column  `MAX(Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar) as maxvalue` a max value of `Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar` column. Thats right?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: Is `MAX(Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar) OVER () as maxvalue` what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
    s.Segment_ID,
    i.Date,
    i.NumAll,
    MAX(i.AverageDailyIntensCar) AS maxAverageDailyIntensCar,
    t.the_geom
FROM dbo.Segment_ID s
LEFT JOIN dbo.Track t ON s.Segment_ID = t.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Intensity i ON s.Segment_ID = i.Segment_ID
WHERE i.Date = '20090814'
GROUP BY 
    s.Segment_ID,
    i.Date,
    i.NumAll,
    t.the_geom
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT 
      s.Segment_ID
    , i.[Date]
    , i.NumAll
    , mx.maxAverageDailyIntensCar
    , t.the_geom
FROM dbo.Segment_ID s
LEFT JOIN dbo.Track t ON s.Segment_ID = t.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Intensity i ON s.Segment_ID = i.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
          i.Segment_ID
        , maxAverageDailyIntensCar = MAX(i.AverageDailyIntensCar)
    FROM dbo.Intensity i
    GROUP BY i.Segment_ID
) mx ON s.Segment_ID = mx.Segment_ID
WHERE i.[Date] = '20090814'
```

Comment: ???Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar should not be in group, and be used only once ...

Comment: Im update question please look at it. And in your query: Type "geometry " cant be used in group by. Its for column `the_geom`

Comment: Its nice, but give uncorrect result. Its try to found max value of whole `i.maxAverageDailyIntensCar`. But not found it.

Comment: For example max value in this column ~30 000 but its found only ~6000.

Answer (score 2):

`Max` is an aggregate function, you can not use it with column name. if you are using `Max` then use group by.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024489/sql-server-max-statement-returns-multiple-results)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
Segment_ID.Segment_ID,
Intensity.Date,
Intensity.NumAll,
Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar,
MAX(Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar)OVER() as maxvalue,
Track.the_geom
FROM Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID=Track.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Intensity ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID=Intensity.Segment_ID
where (DATEPART(yy, Intensity.Date) = 2009
AND DATEPART(mm, Intensity.Date) = 08
AND DATEPART(dd, Intensity.Date) = 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte AS
(
SELECT 
Segment_ID.Segment_ID,
Intensity.Date,
Intensity.NumAll,
Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar
Track.the_geom
FROM Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID=Track.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Intensity ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID=Intensity.Segment_ID
where (DATEPART(yy, Intensity.Date) = 2009
AND DATEPART(mm, Intensity.Date) = 08
AND DATEPART(dd, Intensity.Date) = 14)
)
Select *,(Select MAX(AverageDailyIntensCar) from CTE) as maxvalue
from CTE
```

Comment: Its nice and work. But i cant use `with` construction. Its possible to do it without `with`.